# transparent canvas video Safari issues

Tags: javascript, video, canvas, safari

I'd like to build a website with a small start animation which should support transparency.
I found this small tutorial that is working great: http://www.sciencelifeny.com/transparency/transparency.html

It is based on a video that shows both the RGB channel and the alpha channel. In the JS application, the video data is read, merged and rendered to a canvas element.

I implemented this solution and it works in Chrome and FF, but not in Safari.

Here is my implementation: https://github.com/niels-garve/canvas-video

Can someone please have a look and help me with this? That would be so great! I am at a loss and need help.

I tried a few things:

- I thought that creating the HTML structure by using `document.createElement` expressions would crash Safari, but it doesn't seem like that.
- Also the 2D context is working well. I tried to render a simple square on canvas, which was working out well in Safari. It seems it doesn't like the video data?

I will try to document my code on GitHub this weekend, but I really followed the instructions in the above tutorial.

I would be so glad if someone helped me out with this. Thank you so much in advance!

Cheers
Niels

Comment: I'm running this small example on a local webserver, so there are no cross-domain issues.

Answer (score 0):

I deployed my solution on the development environment I'm working with, where the animation is running well on Safari. So I guess there's something wrong with my local websever configurations.

Cheers

Niels